# updating counter increment when click on link in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have an audio file on public folder like this-

```
 @foreach ($songs as $song)
     <a href="{{asset('/audio/' . $song->song)}}" download="" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info download" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download">Download</i>
        </button>
     </a>
 @endforeach
```

So, when i click that button it downloads the song. i have a song database where i put the song and a column `download_count` set to default(0). I want to increase the `download_count` every time the button is clicked. so how can i pass this logic to controller for updating the database?

Comment: You can call a controller method instead of file. And in this method you can write logic to add count to database and download the file dynamically.

Comment: you can make a download method on click download you will call that download method .there you can use counter

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update your download count dynamically via Ajax.

A simple example:

```
@foreach ($songs as $song)
   <a href="{{asset('/audio/' . $song->song)}}">
     <button type="button" class="download" data-id="{{ $song->id}}">Download</button>
   </a>
@endforeach

<script>
$('.download').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: "/update_download_count",
   type:"POST",
   data: {
     song_id:   $(this).attr('data-id')
   },
   success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (request, status, error) {
     console.log('code: '+request.status+"\n"+'message: '+request.responseText+"\n"+'error: '+error);
   }
 });
});
</script>
```

**Your route:**

```
Route::post('/update_download_count', 'SongController@updateDownloadCount');
```

**Your controller:**

```
public function updateDownloadCount(){
 $song_id = $_POST['song_id'];
 // your database update logic
}
```

Comment: I wrote my controller:                                                                            public function updateDownloadCount(){
 $song_id = $_POST['song_id'];
 $song->download_count += 1;
         $song->save();
} But it still doesnot do anything, my download_count vaule is still 0 :(

Comment: ajax can't update my database somehow. I can't figure out why.

Comment: no error.. just database is not updated..download_count appears to be 0. I think there is something wrong with ajax call..

Comment: If you get an error 500 in the console it's because laravel needs to verify the csrf token before making an ajax call. You should have something like: $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      }); somewhere

Comment: Any update ? Would be nice to close this question :)